How to protect a μc IO pin that might see voltage when μc is off but must read it when μc is on?
I have a small voltage source which I'm using as a detector for power in another circuit.  It connects to a microcontroller pin.  Sometimes it's active when the microcontroller is not powered up, but when the microcontroller is powered up it needs to read the pin to see if the source is on.  How can I safely do this?
I've found that just allowing the microcontroller to power up through the diode in the input pin eventually destroys the pin.  I was thinking maybe a FET or NPN controlled from another uc pin, and an external pull-down on the pin itself?  But I don't know what's best here and would appreciate advice.

Please be more specific. Show us a schematic, tell us what voltage source you are using ect.

Source is a 120 VAC in 5V 2W out isolated  encapsulated module.  I'll try to to add a schematic later, though it's exactly what you would expect: the uc pin on one side, the source on the other.  I don't have any definite idea about how to connect them (correctly).

Have you considered an optocoupler?

Here are a couple of options:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the left, pull-up resistor R1 holds IN pin potential at +5V, but the diode enables a LOW input \$V_X=0V\$ to "pull" that potential down to near zero. The diode prevents current from flowing into the pin. This requires that \$V_X \ge 0\$, never negative.
A better solution is on the right, where X is completely isolated from the MCU by the transistor's gate, and no current can flow between X and the MCU side. The digital signal at X is inverted, of course. M1 should have \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ well below \$V_X\$, so that it switches fully on when X is high.

Thinking about the first proposed solution with just the diode, I'm not 100% sure it would work for the situation I describe in the question (where X is the output of an isolated supply), because is it really known in this case that X can sink current when the supply is off?  It seems like it might be "disconnected" rather than "GND".  I guess this would be fixed with a load on X (e.g. 1 k vs 10k R1 in your schematic).  I do have a load like this but I didn't specify it in the question (and call the supply a "detector").

@BrittonKerin is it really isolated though? The grounds of the two systems must be common, and X is only sinking a tiny current through R1 to that common ground. It's true that there's no current for the MOSFET solution, but you still have to have a common ground. If you need total isolation then SimonB's anser is the best way to go.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
An optocoupler would solve the problem.  The phototransistor is driven off the same supply as the microprocessor, so the GPIO will never see any voltage unless the power is on.
The two -ve supplies can be connected or not, whichever works best for the rest of the circuit.

100k resistor.
A series resistor high enough that current through it is too low to damage the microcontroller, but enough that the digital input can see voltage when it is present.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
NPN transistor common emitter.
prevents the external circuit from putting any voltage on the input.
inverts the signal high vs low.

The NPN or FET idea is likely cheapest.
Let the external monitored voltage control the transistor. Read the transistor output with MCU. The MCU can use internal pull-up resistor or external resistor to MCU supply.
There are also logic ICs that can have 5V on input when unpowered with the MCU.
Some MCUs have 5V tolerant pins that can handle more than 3.3V whem unpowered because there are no protection clamp diodes, but your MCU might not have those.

Given that kind of source you likely need to add a load resistor to get a timely response to the removal of 120VAC.
If your circuit is in a benign EMI environment, a simple BJT will work well.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R1 discharges the output filter capacitor and provides the typical 10% of full-load that the module probably calls for. It's actually a little higher than the 125 ohms that would be required to get 0.2W but should be okay and also it is low enough (167mW) that a 250mW rated resistor should be reliable.
The capacitor C1 is typically included in your module and it will conduct EMI from the 120VAC lines to your GND and could cause issues if there is a lot of EMI. In the latter case, you can replace the BJT with an optoisolator and lower R2 to get 5 or 10mA through the LED. Maybe 510 ohms and increase the R1 bleeder resistor 150 ohms to 180 ohms or so.

I think I have a 2k load or so on it now.  I originally added that because I thought it might need some load for stability, but I didn't think it would need 10%.  It does take a little time to discharge but I currently just wait for it to do so.  I went back and looked and can't find anything like 10% in the datasheet for the part (Mean Well IRM-02-5).  Is this a normal requirement for this sort of part?

It’s more common for DC-DC modules, but that one is fully spec’d down to 0mA, so no worries.
